# Ruby If condition that looks at all contents of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, conditional-statements, ruby-1.9

basically I am trying to write an if condition that looks at all the contents of an array to judge whether that condition is true.

Basically, I want to do:

```
SubScale.all.each do |ss|
  if ss.key IN(scales)
    execute this code
  end
end
```

Where scales in an array and I want the code to be executed if ss.key is any entry in that array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `Array#include`? :

```
scales.include?(ss.key)
```

Answer (score 4):

More general than [`Array#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000265)—which requires you to check by value—is [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001500):

```
SubScale.all.each do |ss|
  # Run the code if the value is an exact match
  run_code if scales.include?(ss.key)
end

SubScale.all.each do |ss|
  # Run the code if the block returns a truthy value
  run_code if scales.any?{ |scale| scale.downcase == ss.key.downcase }
end
```

Finally, if it is an exact match you want, and speed turns out to be an issue (profile first!), you can trade memory for performance by using a hash to look up your key in O(1) instead of O(n) time:

```
scale_lookup = Hash[ scales.map{ |s| [s,true] } ]
SubScale.all.each do |ss|
  run_code if scale_lookup[ss.key]
end
```

Comment: There's also [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/Set.html) if the Hash approach fits the situation and you want to be a stickler about semantics.

Comment: @mu You know, I was going to include Set...but in practice I never use it since Hash is faster, more convenient, and just as effective (unless you want to perform set operations like intersections and such). Still, good of you to note it.

Comment: I tend to do the same but I figured it w worth a mention but not worth a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

scales.include?(ss.key) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If `scales` has many elements and so does `SubScale.all` I would suggest creating temporary set (or hash):

```
require "set"

scales_set = Set.new(scales)

....each do |ss|
  if scales_set.include?(ss.key)
    ...
  end
end
```

This could be much faster.

P.S. Hash seems to be faster than set:

```
scales_hash = scales.inject({}) { |h, e| h[e] = true; h }

....each do |ss|
  if scales_hash.has_key?(ss.key)
    ...
  end
end
```